# Why can't I print outside loop

Tags: python, loops, printing

[I am a code beginner.Can anyone tell me what happend if I get a syntaxerror when putting the "print" outside the loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgUOV.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you are using an interactive interpreter shell. You should hit <kbd>enter</kbd> after the last line of the loop before you try to print.

In future questions please write your code in the question body instead of attaching a screenshot.